# Smooth animations in Android camera preview

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask

I'm trying to create online scanner using Android and image recognition API. I'm trying to create nice layout with animated trigger. It will look [like this](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/4205/itraffapiapplivescan.jpg).

I've currently everything and it runs great with one exception: animations. Animation of this blue trigger is OK, but when AsyncTask is posting photo to API, animation of laser is hanging for a while. What should I do to prevent such behaviour?

This is code of my animations:

```
final View laser = findViewById(R.id.laser);
laser.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

final View trigger = findViewById(R.id.trigger);
Animation fadeAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);
fadeAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
fadeAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
fadeAnimation.setDuration(3000);
trigger.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
trigger.startAnimation(fadeAnimation);

trigger.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Animation translateDownAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.25f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.75f);
        final Animation translateUpAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.75f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.25f);
        translateDownAnimation.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
        translateDownAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        translateDownAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        translateUpAnimation.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
        translateUpAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        translateUpAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        translateDownAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            translateUpAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        translateDownAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                laser.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scanner_line_down);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                laser.startAnimation(translateUpAnimation);
            }
        });
        translateUpAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                laser.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scanner_line_up);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                laser.startAnimation(translateDownAnimation);
            }
        });
        laser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        laser.startAnimation(translateDownAnimation);
    }
});
```

If it will be helpfull I could prepare proper .apk file.

Comment: Have You tried to profile?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Decoding YUI image takes a lot of time, so I've put it in new asynctask, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure there's that decoding, but probably it can be moved before / after animations. Also, take a look if any large allocations happens during start animation (so, lot of GC might happen). Actually, there's nothing specific in provided code, so I'm sure issue is not in it (but You still can create animations sometime before You need them to play).

Comment: But animations are playing along with decoding - this is scaneer app, so I don't want to stop animations when single camera frame is evaluated.